# Bootstrap disrupts hilite.me generated code

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to embed this C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct node
{
int data;
struct node *next;
};
struct node *start=NULL,*newnode,*ptr,*pre;
int num,val;
void create();
void display();
void in_beg();
void in_end();
void in_bef();
void in_aft();
void in_sor();
void del_beg();
void del_end();
void del_node();
void del_aft();
void del_sor();
void del_list();
void main()
{
int option;
clrscr();
do
{
printf("\n\n***********MAIN MENU*******");
printf("\n 1:Create List");
printf("\n 2:Display List");
printf("\n 3:Add a node in beginning");
printf("\n 4:add a node at the end");
printf("\n 5:add a node before a given node");
printf("\n 6:add a node after a given node");
printf("\n 7:add a node in sorted linked list");
printf("\n 8:delete a node from begining");
printf("\n 9:delete a node from end");
printf("\n 10:delete a given node");
printf("\n 11:delete a node after a given node");
printf("\n 12:delete a node from sorted Linked List");
printf("\n 13:delete the entire list");
printf("\n 14:Exit");
printf("\n ***************************\n");
printf("\n Enter your choice:");
scanf("%d",&option);
switch(option)
{
case 1:
create();
printf("\n Linked List Created");
break;
case 2:
display();
break;
case 3:
in_beg();
break;
case 4:
in_end();
break;
case 5:
in_bef();
break;
case 6:
in_aft();
break;
case 7:
in_sor();
break;
case 8:
del_beg();
break;
case 9:
del_end();
break;
case 10:
del_node();
break;
case 11:
del_aft();
break;
case 12:
del_sor();
break;
case 13:
del_list();
break;
}
}
while(option!=14);
getch();
}
void create()
{
printf("\n enter -1 to end");
printf("\n enter the data:");
scanf("%d",&num);
while(num!=-1)
{
newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
newnode->data=num;
if(start==NULL)
{
newnode->next=newnode;
start=newnode;
return;
}
else
{
ptr=start;
while(ptr->next!=start)
{
ptr=ptr->next;
}
newnode->next=start;
ptr->next=newnode;
return;
}
}
}
void display()
{
ptr=start;
printf("\n");
while(ptr->next!=start)
{
printf("\t%d",ptr->data);
ptr=ptr->next;
}
printf("\t%d",ptr->data);
}
void in_beg()
{
printf("\n enter the data:");
scanf("%d",&num);
newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
newnode->data=num;
ptr=start;
while(ptr->next!=start)
{
ptr=ptr->next;
}
ptr->next=newnode;
newnode->next=start;
start=newnode;
}
void in_end()
{
printf("\n enter the data:");
scanf("%d",&num);
newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
newnode->data=num;
ptr=start;
while(ptr->next!=start)
{
ptr=ptr->next;
}
ptr->next=newnode;
newnode->next=start;
}
void in_bef()
{
printf("\n enter the value before which the data has to be inserted:");
scanf("%d",&val);
newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
ptr=start;
if(ptr->data==val)
{
printf("\n Enter the data");
scanf("%d",&num);
in_beg();
}
else
{
newnode->data=num;
while(ptr->data!=val)
{
pre=ptr;
ptr=ptr->next;
}
newnode->next=ptr;
pre->next=newnode;
}
}
void in_aft()
{
printf("\n enter the value after which the data has to be inserted:");
scanf("%d",&val);
printf("\n enter the data:");
scanf("%d",&num);
newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
newnode->data=num;
ptr=start;
while(pre->data!=val)
{
pre=ptr;
ptr=ptr->next;
}
newnode->next=ptr;
pre->next=newnode;
}
void in_sor()
{
printf("\n enter the data:");
scanf("%d",&num);
newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
newnode->data=num;
ptr=start;
while(ptr->data<num)
{
pre=ptr;
ptr=ptr->next;
if(ptr==start)
break;
}
if(ptr==start)
{
pre->next=newnode;
newnode->next=start;
//start=newnode;
return;
}
else
{
newnode->next=ptr;
pre->next=newnode;
return;
}
}
void del_beg()
{
ptr=start;
while(ptr->next!=start)
{
ptr=ptr->next;
}
ptr->next=start->next;
free(start);
start=ptr->next;
return;
}
void del_end()
{
ptr=start;
while(ptr->next!=start)
{
pre=ptr;
ptr=ptr->next;
}
pre->next=ptr->next;
free(ptr);
return;
}
void del_node()
{
printf("Enter the value of the node which has to be deleted");
scanf("%d",&val);
ptr=start;
if(ptr->data==val)
{
del_beg();
}
else
{
while(ptr->data!=val)
{
pre=ptr;
ptr=ptr->next;
}
pre->next=ptr->next;
free(ptr);
}
}
void del_aft()
{
printf("Enter the value after which the node which has to be deleted");
scanf("%d",&val);
ptr=start;
while(pre->data!=val)
{
pre=ptr;
ptr=ptr->next;
}
pre->next=ptr->next;
if(ptr==start)
{
start=pre->next;
}
free(ptr);
}
void del_sor()
{
printf("Enter the value of the node which has to be deleted");
scanf("%d",&val);
ptr=start;
if(ptr->data==val)
{
del_beg();
return;
}
else
{
while(ptr->data!=val)
{
pre=ptr;
ptr=ptr->next;
}
pre->next=ptr->next;
free(ptr);
}
}
void del_list()
{
ptr=start;
while(ptr->next!=start)
{
del_end();
free(start);
}
printf("\n Succesfully List is deleted");
}
```

in HTML webpage using beautifier (http://hilite.me/). My desired style was 'Monokai'. I have also added External CSS Spreadsheet (bootstrap).
After trying code, the Bootstrap CSS file replaces the black background with plain White background and turns the hilite.me generated code to a very unreadable code.

I tried using customized Bootstrap and found that 'Code' component of Bootstrap CSS was creating problem,but when I used customized Bootstrap, the glyphicons doesn't show up.
I need help in solving this problem.

Webpage code :
http://pastebin.com/fxLrKYN9